# Not to marshal root element from RootElement JAXB object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Eg. my xml is

```
<RootElement>
    <element1>A</element1>
    <element2>B</element2>
    <ElementList>
        <element>1</element>
        <element>2</element>
        <element>3</element>
    </ElementList>
</RootElement>
```

In this case, I am getting RootElement JaxB object which contains object of element1 and element2. So I want to write only these two element from RootElement object in xml file.

Comment: I was facing similar issue.. You can follow solution mention @ http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html